# How can I display a HTML element at a precise location?

Tags: html, tags, coordinates

My question is almost stupid because I think I know the answer but I wanna be sure. Does it exist a mechanism to be able to put a tag at a specific location. I mean, I can set the coordinates X and Y of a tag. Maybe this specific tag should be placed in a special parent tag?

Do you know an another way to do this?

An example should be something like this :

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="container" >
      <img src="..."  x="40" y="0" />
      <img src="..."  x=70" y ="10"/>
         ....
    </div>
   ....
```

Many thanks for you attention,

Bat

Comment: There isn't a concept of Cartesian coordinates in HTML... it's just a document tree.

Comment: do you want to move a tag or an html element?

Comment: Can you give us an example code and explain what exactly you want to achieve? Place what where in relation to what?

Comment: Are you really talking about the html source, or are you looking at the rendered page (in that case, css might help ;-) )?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you want an element to be placed at a specific location on the page, you can give it `position: absolute` in CSS, together with it's position relative to the last parent element that has a position value of `relative` or `absolute`.

For instance, with this HTML

```
<div id="square"></div>
```

Can be placed 100px off the top and left of the page with this CSS

```
#square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

---

Given your example, no, not entirely. You can use the `style` attribute for the same effect though:

```
<div id="square" style="top: 100px; left: 100px;"></div>
```

Assuming `#square` has `position: absolute` applied to it from a stylesheet already. It's best however if you incorporated this into a stylesheet, since content and presentation should be separate.

Answer (score 1):

You can do absolute positioning via CSS.  See http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Absolute_Layouts